# frozensetの要素を取得する方法で困っております。

Tags: python

pythonでnetworkXを用いて、頂点のラベル付けとしてfrozensetを用いているのですが、
frozensetの要素を取得する方法が調べてもこれといったサイトを見つけることができなかったのでこちらに書き込まさせていただきました。
以下に例を示しておきますのでご参考にしていたければ幸いです。

例
・frozenset([1, 2])
やりたいこと：要素1,2を取得したい
困っていること：要素の取得ができない

Answer (score 2):

for以外の選択肢もあります。取り出してどう使いたいかによって選んで下さい。

```
>>> f = frozenset([1,2])
>>> f
frozenset({1, 2})
>>> list(f)
[1, 2]
>>> set(f)
{1, 2}
>>> tuple(f)
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setには順番がないためlistのようには取得できません
そのため、forで取り出す必要があります。

```
s = frozenset([1, 2])
for value in s:
    print(value) // 1, 2
```

Comment: なるほど、listと同じように取れるものだという認識が間違いでした。
forで取り出す必要があるのですね、ご回答ありがとうございます。